# Using wildcard in Angular on refresh

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm building a website on a MEAN Stack. This website contains a lot of pages with citynames. I have created one template for all citynames where some information is changed on city select. I've also managed to use a Wildcard function in Angular where the chosen cityname is also displayed in the URL. But the only thing that is not working is when I refresh the page on a certain cityname. The DB info is not being showed.

This is the page where the cityname is being selected:

```
<div ng-controller="DataCtrl" class="plumber-by-city col-sm-12 home-text-col">
<div class="title-1">Zoek op plaatsnaam</div>
   <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-change="changePath('loodgieter-in')" ng-options="item as item.city for item in items"></select><span class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
</div>
```

This is the page where the selected city and other info is being showed:

```
<div class="align-content-inner" ng-controller="DataCtrl2">
<div class="title-1">Plumbers in {{selectedItem.city}}</div>
   <p>
     {{selectedItem.phoneLG}} and {{selectedItem.phoneAG}}
   </p>
   <p>
     {{selectedItem.city}}
   </p>
</div>
```

This is the controller and the service:

```
app.controller('DataCtrl', function($scope,$http,getData,$location){

  getData.getCity().then(function(response){
    $scope.items = response.data;
    $scope.selectedItem = response.data[0];
  });
});

$scope.changePath = function(path) {
   getData.setItem($scope.selectedItem);
   $location.path('/'+ path +'/' + $scope.selectedItem.city);
};

app.factory('getData', function($http){
  return {
    getCity: function(){
      return $http.get("/getdata");
    },
    setItem: function(item) {
      this.item = item;
    },
    getItem: function() {
      return this.item;
    },
  };
});
```

And the second controller on the next page:

```
app.controller('DataCtrl2', function($scope,$http,getData,$location){
  getData.getItem();
  $scope.selectedItem = getData.getItem();

  $scope.changePath = function(path) {
    $location.path('/'+ path +'/' + $scope.selectedItem.city);
  };
});
```

Now when the user refreshes the page on a cityname, let's say: localhost:3000/loodgieter-in/Amsterdam, the page refreshes but does not show the cityname data.

Now I know that Angular re-initialzises when the page refreshes, so is there a way that when a user types the url including a cityname, the data that belongs to that chosen cityname is returned and displayed in that page?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you F5, or refresh a page, Angular is initialized again, so any value you where storing in your service, is lost.

When you do:

```
 getData.getItem();
 $scope.selectedItem = getData.getItem();
```

You are getting undefined, because item on the service is undefined. (nothing has been set yet)

EDIT: You can find the city name by the location path:

```
$location.path().substr($location.path().lastIndexOf('/')+1)
```

Comment: I know indeed that Angular is re-initialized when the page refreshes, but I was wondering if there is a way when the user types the url and a cityname, the data that belongs to that cityname is displayed in that page

Comment: Well, as you are not using a routing directive that may help you with resolves (ui router or ngRoute), you may retrieve the name of the city you pass the url and try to call your backend for that info.
May be with something like this: $location.path().substr($location.path.lastIndexOf('/')+1)

Comment: I am using ng-Route for my routing

Comment: Then, may be you can use $routeParams to get the city by the url and then get the city information on init of your controller. (define a init function with everything you want the controller to do on init, like getting data of the current city)

Comment: I managed to get the value from the $routeParams and also all the data from DB. But somehow I need to match the $routeParams with the data from DB so this specific data will be retrieved. Is there somekind of regEX function in Angular?

Comment: You can use javascript match method. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp